Various installations of python on my MacBook
I am doing more or less a find . -iname "*python*" -type d in my MacOS and I find numerous python installations.
I am unable to figure out which is which and what is its purpose so I was wondering whether someone can point me to some documentation.
Some examples:
./Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app

./System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework

./System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Python 3.11

./System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11
./System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9
./System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12

(I am assuming the later are brew installations.
./System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12

Any help would be much appreciated.

What do you want to do with this software you installed on your Mac? We’re going to have a hard time understanding your goals unless you can narrow down what “any help” looks like to you.

My question was more on the multitude of paths, e.g. /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew vs System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Python and so on and so forth

You installed all of these, macOS has not shipped a Python since macOS 12.4.
The CLT (Command Line Tools) brings a copy of Python 3.9.
The copies of 3.9, 3.11, and 3.12 that have been installed came from Homebrew.  It's not clear from your posting which are actually installed, some of those files may be debris from previous upgrades done by Homebrew.
